# Any Videoconferencing software for Ubuntu?

Tags: voip, video-streaming

First of all, thanks for reading and helping! I have a quick question. I need to know if there is a software option which I could use to connect to a Videoconference Bridge (such as a Polycom RMX or Tandberg VCS, etc) via IP. Web options are also welcome.

Answer (score -1):

I would give a look to https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+10
ConfBridge in Asterisk might fulfill your demand.